# Simple way to colour alternate output lines in bash

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, colors

I have need to grep an entire directory for a string, and I get about 50 results. I would like to colour each second line, either text colour or background colour. Best would be a script that I can pipe the output of any command to, and so that it spits out the same (albeit coloured) output.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not very pretty but does the trick:

(save this to `foo.bash` and do `grep whatever wherever | ./foo.bash`)

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
  echo -e "\e[1;31m$line"
  read line
  echo -e "\e[1;32m$line"
done
echo -en "\e[0m"
```

Here you can find the [list of color codes in bash](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt).

Comment: Very neat, can also be used as a function to avoid a second script.

Comment: I like this, but you forgot to reset afterwards: 
echo -en '\e[0m';

Comment: Might be better to reset it after the loop.

Comment: Can you also create a function out of it?

Comment: (About edit history of this answer.) I manually reverted an edit because its explanation seemed suspect.  The original bash code worked.  The semicolons might be superfluous but as the previous editor who changed it to double quotes was incorrect about their necessity, I didn't feel I should remove them as his or her edit had done.

Comment: @JayC: Try `echo "foo   bar" | ./foo.bash` or `echo "*" | ./foo.bash`.

Comment: Whitespace issues.  Ok

Comment: Changed it back to Scott's modifications as the use of the quotes preserves spacing.

Comment: @JayC: It’s not just spacing. With the original version, wildcards in the input turn into lists of files in the output; e.g., `echo "*" | ./foo.bash`.

Comment: Ah geez. Of course, that's essentially an injection attack.  I should know better. Sorry.

Comment: This will also print an extra line if the number of lines is odd. I think you can fix it by changing the second two lines of the loop body to: read line && echo -e "\e[1;32m$line" (so if read line fails, it doesn't echo anything)

Comment: In addition to Andrew's suggestion, you must use the text formatting reset sequence (`\e[0m` or `\e(B\e[m`) on both loop `echo` lines for use cases that will process only a portion of the output (e.g. pipes to `head` or `tail`). The loop would take the form `while read line; do echo -ne "<color sequence 1>" && echo -e "\e[0m"; read line && echo -ne "<color sequence 2>$line" && echo -e "\e[0m"; done`

Answer (score 5):

Perl is installed on many systems. You could have it alternate for you:

```
grep -r whatever somedir/ | perl -pe '$_ = "\033[1;29m$_\033[0m" if($. % 2)'
```

In Perl `$.` can be substituted with `$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER` if you prefer readability.

Comment: more subtle version, with every second line grey: `perl -pe '$_ = "\033[2m$_\033[22m" if($. % 2)'`

Answer (score 3):

This is to delineate wrapped lines I presume?
This shell script uses a background color from the [256 color](http://www.frexx.de/xterm-256-notes/) palette,
so as not to interfere with other highlighting that grep --color might do.

```
#!/bin/sh
c=0
while read line; do
  [ $(($c%2)) -eq 1 ] && printf "\033[48;5;60m"
  printf "%s\033[0m\n" "$line"
  c=$(($c+1))
done
```

This has the caveat that backslashes etc. within the line will be mangled,
so treat this as pseudo code for reimplementation

Comment: Hah, if I had have known about --color I probably wouldn't have needed this, but both are good. Thanks for the thoughtful solution.

Comment: The given link is not active anymore. Maybe this one helps: https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting (Sept. 2021)

Answer (score 2):

and here is the same in python;

```
import sys
for line_number,line in enumerate(sys.stdin.readlines()):
    print '%s[1;3%dm%s%s[0m' % (chr(27),(line_number % 2+1),line,chr(27)),
```